# Character as Operator for equations

Tags: java, operators, character

I don't think this is possible as it would get annoying in many many circumstances but I thought it would at least be safe to ask, is there a way to make:

```
char operator = (Character) Utils.getProblemOperator(onPrev
            ? getPreviousMode()
            : getMode());
Integer answer = -1, uanswer = Utils.getInt(answerField.getText());
        if (operator == '+')
            answer = (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][0] + (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][1];
        else if (operator == '-')
            answer = (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][0] - (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][1];
        else if (operator == '×')
            answer = (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][0] * (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][1];
        else if (operator == '÷')
            answer = (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][0] / (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][1];
```

Focusing on this part:

```
answer = (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][0] + (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][1];
```

Into something like:

```
answer = (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][0] operator (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][1];
```

The final outcome would be:

```
boolean onPrev = (boolean) pInfo[1][3];
        char opperator = (Character) Utils.getProblemOperator(onPrev
                ? getPreviousMode()
                : getMode());
        Integer answer = -1, uanswer = Utils.getInt(answerField.getText());
            answer = (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][0] operator (int) pInfo[onPrev ? 1 : 0][1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. I remember I was building a calculator awhile ago and ended up using a switch statement I believe. if else is fine as well.